# What is going on behind the binding of this textbook?

Tags: books

I’m not sure if this is the right SE for this, but since it’s a textbook, I figured Literature or any other fictional genre SE wouldn’t be right.

I have a hardback cover of *Classical Mechanics* by John R. Taylor, Printed/ published by University Science Books, and today as the binding was coming off, I noticed the strangest thing; there was text behind the binding of the book, completely inaccessible outside of tearing the binding off (pictures included). I’ve never heard of this happening with any kind of book, but my first guess is that it’s some kind of recycling method. The title of the text behind the binding is *Cognitive Behavior Therapy*, which just adds to the mystery.

Has anyone ever heard of this happening with textbooks? Does anyone know what is going on here?

[image: Image of Binding with Text]

Comment: Ask the publisher.

Comment: This is normal. It is paper recycling at the book binding stage.

Comment: Would have been cooler if it contains a map to some lost treasure or a proof to a Millennium Prize problem.

Comment: The text contains some distinctive phrases that make it traceable to _Cognitive behavior therapy: basics and beyond_ by Judith S. Beck.  But puzzlingly, that's from a different publisher (Guilford Publications).